# Pop-up over image with link

Tags: html, image, hyperlink, popup, hover

I have these images that redirect to links and I want to when I hover on them there would pop up a text. How to do that? I tried w3schools tutorials but they don't include divs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>


div.folder1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;

}

div.folder2 {
position: absolute;
top: 20%;
left: 40%;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="folder1"> 
<a href="yourlinkhere" target="_self">
<img src="https://78.media.tumblr.com/c00202bad8ae39931e34a7efa861d18b/tumblr_p70bjja6xI1x5vw3ao1_500.png" height="46" width="57" />
</a>  
</div>

<div class="folder2"> 
<a href="yourlinkhere" target="_self">
<img src="https://78.media.tumblr.com/c00202bad8ae39931e34a7efa861d18b/tumblr_p70bjja6xI1x5vw3ao1_500.png" height="46" width="57" />
</a>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1.css"/>
<script>
function popup1() {
var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup1");
popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
function popup2() {
var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup2");
popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>
<title></title>

</head>
<body>

<div class="folder1"> 
<div class="popup" onmouseover="popup1()">
<span class="popuptext" id="myPopup1">Popup text...</span>

<a href="yourlinkhere" target="_self">
<img src="https://78.media.tumblr.com/c00202bad8ae39931e34a7efa861d18b/tumblr_p70bjja6xI1x5vw3ao1_500.png" height="46" width="57"
</a>  
</div>
</div>

<div class="folder2"> 
<div class="popup" onmouseover="popup2()">
<span class="popuptext" id="myPopup2">Popup text</span>
<a href="yourlinkhere" target="_self">
<imgsrc="https://78.media.tumblr.com/c00202bad8ae39931e34a7efa861d18b/tumblr_p70bjja
6xI1x5vw3ao1_500.png" height="46" width="57"
</a>  
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.folder1 {
position: absolute;
top: 30%;
left: 50%;

}

.folder2 {
position: absolute;
top: 20%;
left: 40%;

}
.popup {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
}


.popup .popuptext {
visibility: hidden;
width: 160px;
background-color: #555;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 6px;
padding: 8px 0;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
bottom: 125%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -80px;
}


.popup .popuptext::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -5px;
border-width: 5px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}


.popup .show {
visibility: visible;
-webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
animation: fadeIn 1s
}


@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
from {opacity: 0;} 
to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
from {opacity: 0;}
to {opacity:1 ;}
}
}
```

Comment: This is the w3schools code, and it does work, you just need to add the div to the folder div, and you need to close it, before closing the folder div(which I did in this code), and need to add the onmouseover="function()" command

Comment: How and where do I have to add the onmouseover="function()" ?

Comment: It's in the code, I've added it to it, it's in the popup div